# Is it possible to embed a React-Native view as a subview in a native android project?

Tags: react-native

I'm integrating react-native to my pure java android project. I just want some item of my native ListView show a react-native view. I don't want to change the whole ListView to react-native.

Is there any way to do this? 
I've tried to add ReactRootView as a subview to some other view, it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my Activity went wrong.
RN requires support lib 23.0.1, but the ConstraintLayout is not compatible with support lib 23.0.1.
Just use any other Layout for the root view of the Activity.

Comment: Still got the problem on Android 4.4, setContentView will show the ReactRootView , but add it on a ListView will not show the ReactRootView. Android 6.0 can add as subview.